# Зачем обнулять STARTUPINFO?

Tags: winapi, c++

```
STARTUPINFO sti;
ZeroMemory(&sti,sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
sti.cb=sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того же, для чего и нужна инициализация любой переменной: иначе там будут содержаться случайные значения, которые могут быть неправильно истолкованы кодом, который пользуется этой структурой.

(Кроме того, технически пользоваться неинициализированной структурой есть undefined behaviour, оптимизатор имеет право устроить вам много сюрпризов.)

Кстати, `ZeroMemory` — это довольно старый метод инициализации. В современных версиях языка лучше делать так:

```
STARTUPINFO sti = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
```

(поскольку `sb` — первое поле в структуре) или так

```
STARTUPINFO sti = {};
sti.sb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
```

(если вы не хотите вносить неявную зависимость от layout'а структуры).

В чистом C, если я не ошибаюсь, возможна более выразительная конструкция:

```
STARTUPINFO sti = { .cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
```

Comment: А зачем пишут GetStartupInfo(&sti) после объявления, но перед созданием процесса? Там же ещё ничего не будет. Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: @strol: [Документация](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683230.aspx) говорит:

> Retrieves the contents of the STARTUPINFO structure that was specified when the calling process was created.

То есть, возвращается информация для текущего процесса, а не какого-то другого, который только будет создан потом.